# hacer clic y mostrar información tipo "modal" solo al ser responsivo

Tags: html, css, responsive, programación-móvil, style

espero puedan apoyarme... Tengo un problema con una página web que "estoy creando", (les dejo el ejemplo de cómo quiero que funcione en un **enlace de AMEX**, probándolo en responsivo, y también imágenes de referencia, https://www.americanexpress.com/es-MX/maps?country=MX&near=Ciudad-de-M%C3%A9xico,CDMX&cl=19.4326077,-99.133208)

En la versión que tengo "de escritorio" me funciona correctamente, sin embargo al probar en responsivo el div se pasa a la parte de abajo, quedando así. (Ejemplo en las imágenes), lo que quiero es el mismo funcionamiento como el ejemplo, es decir, que al dar clic a alguno de mis resultados, no me muestre los resultados en el DIV abajo, sino se muestre así mismo como el ejemplo de AMEX, como un tipo "modal" con la opción de volver a los resultados, ¿Alguna idea de cómo buscarlo o emplear alguna solución? Muchas gracias por su apoyo. :D

[image: "Modal" de como se muestra][image: Muestreo de Resultado]

**Estas son las imágenes de mi proyecto.**

[image: Imagen del proyecto][image: Resultados del Proyecto]

Comment: (Resolved) Lo hice a través de un modal, el cual busqué alguna función de PHP para detectar una pantalla móvil y a través de JS pude mandarlo a llamar. PD. no sé aún cómo manejar algunas situaciones en esta plataforma.

Comment: Listo, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

(Resolved) Lo hice a través de un modal, el cual busqué alguna función de PHP para detectar una pantalla móvil y a través de JS pude mandarlo a llamar.